# Tortoise svn lock and user lock

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have recently started using TortoiseSVN, I have specific scenario here to implement. 
We lock the branch for build purpose so no one can commit the code, but if there is any build failure I need that locked branch to be unlock for some specific person (i.e. a user) so that only that user can commit the code. I know this feature is available in other tools i.e. IBM ClearCase. But I need the same feature for TortoiseSVN. Please suggest the possible steps to implement the above scenario if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is just a **CLIENT** application! What you ask about has to be implemented on server-side. For example, you can use [path-based authorization rules](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).

BTW, [locking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html) in Subversion is mostly used for [lock-modify-unlock versioning model](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.lock-unlock.dia-1) and can't really help in you case.